# google sheets query first row mess

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am designing a workflow at work to streamline some tasks. I get some CSV from a database which I want automatically added to a Google Sheet. I stored it on a Google Drive, got the direct download link and used it with IMPORTDATA on sheet1. So far so good.

The final aim is to create a good way to visualize which rows meet specific conditions, so I thought using a PivotTable might be handy. However, to filter out some of the uninteresting rows, PivotTables are not the way to go, since the filters are quite poor (no possibility of basic filter criteria like =, !=, <, >, etc). So I thought about populating a second sheet with a Query function (with the filtering statements) so that the PivotTable generates a report directly from a filtered source.

The issue (apart from the lag) is that sheet 2 (the one with the query) shows a strange output: the first row, that should contain only the column labels, mixes up the column labels with the value of the cell below them. It is quite baffling. Moreso because it does not happen all along row 1, but it only appears to do so on the first seven columns. So insted of A1 showing "event_id", it actually shows "event_id 106727", which is the value of the fisrt event that should go on A2.

Any thought why this happens?I already checked and there does not seem to be anything wrong with the CSV.

If yyou also have a suggestion of why this whole setup would be a bad idea, please also tell me :P

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `query` command combines multiple header rows into one. And sometimes it mistakes your data for headers. To avoid this, use the optional third parameter to specify the number of header rows:

```
=query(range, query_string, 1)
```

(if there is one header row).

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes!  I was stumped until a search found this post.

Answer (score 0):

The approach by @user6655984 did not work for me, because I was already using the third parameter to customise my header usage.

What occurred was that I was performing 12 queries to different sheets with similarly data. One column was a mixture of strings, such as "12 FPS", "14fps", and numbers. When I began working my way through these columns on all the sheets, I was left with mostly numbers, with a few strings spread throughout.

This caused my query to create a massive first row which concatenated the results of about 6 rows together, cell by cell, before showing the rest of the results, where in this column I edited, all the strings had been removed.

By happenstance I saw this one person [here](https://blog.ouseful.info/2010/11/16/buggy-quirky-behaviour-to-watch-for-in-google-spreadsheets-importdata-and-query-formulae/) who talked about fixing a query issue by making sure that they type-converted the information in a column to be consistent.

This led me to find the following Google support forum post, about queries and data types, from 2019: [Query function not working with specific data set (but working with others)](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2271140)

Giving this a go, I tried turning all the data in all the columns that were equivalent to each other in each sheet I was querying into numbers fixed the issue. Try this if setting headers is not working; make sure you don't have silent type errors.